# Javascript slider slides like crazy after some time

Tags: javascript, slider

If I leave this slider for some time on the site it starts sliding like crazy. How to test this bug? Open bellated.com/vyrai (testing page). You can see big changin photos. Leave it for a min. or two and browse through other browsre tabs and when your back to this site you will see the bug with the slider. any ideas how to fix this?

I am using this script:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() {

        var currentPosition = 0;
        var slideWidth = 673;
        var slides = $('.slide');
        var numberOfSlides = slides.length;
        var slideShowInterval;
        var speed = 6000;

        //Assign a timer, so it will run periodically
        slideShowInterval = setInterval(changePosition, speed);

        slides.wrapAll('<div id="slidesHolder"></div>')

        slides.css({ 'float' : 'left' });

        //set #slidesHolder width equal to the total width of all the slides
        $('#slidesHolder').css('width', slideWidth * numberOfSlides);


        manageNav(currentPosition);

        //tell the buttons what to do when clicked
        $('.nav').bind('click', function() {

            //determine new position
            currentPosition = ($(this).attr('id')=='rightNav')
            ? currentPosition+1 : currentPosition-1;

            //hide/show controls
            manageNav(currentPosition);
            clearInterval(slideShowInterval);
            slideShowInterval = setInterval(changePosition, speed);
            moveSlide();
        });

        function manageNav(position) {
            //hide left arrow if position is first slide
            if(position==0){ $('#leftNav').hide() }
            else { $('#leftNav').show() }
            //hide right arrow is slide position is last slide
            if(position==numberOfSlides-1){ $('#rightNav').hide() }
            else { $('#rightNav').show() }
        }


        //changePosition: this is called when the slide is moved by the timer and NOT when the next or previous buttons are clicked
        function changePosition() {
            if(currentPosition == numberOfSlides - 1) {
                currentPosition = 0;
                manageNav(currentPosition);
            } else {
                currentPosition++;
                manageNav(currentPosition);
            }
            moveSlide();
        }


        //moveSlide: this function moves the slide 
        function moveSlide() {
                $('#slidesHolder').animate({'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)});
        }

    });
</script>
```

html implementation sample:

```
<div id="slideshow"> <div id="slideshowWindow"> 
    <div class="slide"><div class="slideText"> <h2 class="slideTitle">Pas mus kainos visada lanks&#269;ios!</h2> <p class="slideDes">"Tik pas mus &#303;sigykite savo nauj&#261;j&#261; vandens filtravimo sistem&#261; palankiausiomis kainomis".</p> <p class="slideLink"><a href="http://jayreillyportraits.com"></a></p> </div><!--/slideText--> </div><!--/slide--> 
    <div class="slide"><div class="slideText"> <h2 class="slideTitle">Naujas prekybos salonas</h2> <p class="slideDes">"Aplankykite mus naujai atsidariusiame prekybos salone &#352;ilal&#279;je S. Dariaus ir S. Gir&#279;no g. 24".</p> <p class="slideLink"><a href="http://jayreillyportraits.com"></a></p> </div><!--/slideText--> </div><!--/slide--> 
    <div class="slide"><div class="slideText"> <h2 class="slideTitle">Ie&#353;kote galimybi&#371; partneriaujant?</h2> <p class="slideDes">"Susisiekite su mumis ir mes aptarsime abiem pus&#279;ms palankias s&#261;lygas!".</p> <p class="slideLink"><a href="http://jayreillyportraits.com"></a></p> </div><!--/slideText--> </div><!--/slide--> 
    <div class="slide"><div class="slideText"> <h2 class="slideTitle">Turite klausim&#371;?</h2> <p class="slideDes">"Susisiekite su mumis ir m&#363;s&#371; specialistai pasistengs atsakyti  &#303; kiekvien&#261; j&#363;s&#371; u&#382;klaus&#261;.".</p> <p class="slideLink"><a href="http://jayreillyportraits.com"></a></p> </div><!--/slideText--> </div><!--/slide--> 
    </div></div>
```

Comment: its working fine... could you be more specific of what is being crazy.

Comment: @RaghavBhushan You have to follow his directions and switch to another tab, leaving his tab running in the background. And, you'll have to be using Firefox or a WebKit-based browser for the behavior to occur.

Comment: he has no listener for lost wondow focus so how could changing tabs affect it..

Comment: @RaghavBhushan Read my answer to find out :P

Comment: Ive got the same issue, but it is only happening to my website online. Everything is ok at localhost. And I'm using coin slider, a jquery slider. I don't know how to solve it, since everything is fine on their demo site and in other websites I got online as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has multiple causes all working together in a perfect storm:

- You are queueing up new slides based solely on a timer, when you should instead queue them in the callback of the previous slide's animation,
- You are using a browser that supports requestAnimationFrame, and
- You are using jQuery 1.6.2, which includes support for requestAnimationFrame.

When you move away from the tab the slider is running in, a browser with support for requestAnimationFrame will **stop** all animations running in that tab. However, timers will continue to run! When you return to the page, all the queued animations fire immediately, which gives you this runaway effect.

To fix this, the simplest solution would be to upgrade to jQuery 1.7.1, as they've backed out support for requestAnimationFrame() due to inconsistent browser support. But, they'll be bringing it back eventually, so you should really just fix your code.

To fix your code, you should only queue up a new slide animation in the **callback** of the previous slide's `.animate()`. This will ensure you don't blindly queue even when the animations are not running.

Let me know if you need more clarification. tl;dr: Change this:

```
 <script src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

To this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The jQuery bug on the issue has more info: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9381